# Does Airpods Sound muffled after watching video or attending a call or virtual meetings?

Tags: audio, video, ios

I need help with my new Airpods. I got them two months back and they sound perfect every time I listen to music, however, after I join a phone call or watch a video, or join a virtual meeting and go back to music, the Airpods sound muffled. I have tried a lot of solution that I found [online](https://devsjournal.com/airpods-sound-muffled.html), but nothing seems to work.

Has anybody dealt with a Similar issue?

Comment: Have you checked if they work fine with a different device?

Comment: Do they sound muffled?  I would gauge by your own statement that the answer is yes.

Answer (score 0):

**Before anything else you need to assure the correct profile is selected for each task.**

Typically the "headset" (HFP) profile must be used for voice calls (LowFi Mono + microphone) and conversely "headphones" (A2DP) profile (HiFi Stereo, microphone disabled) should be used for everything else that doesn't require simultaneous usage of the microphone.

The latter, A2DP, is used by default in most OSes and the system toggles to HFP on demand by voice and/or video call software or any other with similar requirements. The system *may not* toggle back to A2DP. So, it's up to you to check and select accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

It's normal that audio quality is reduced when a call comes in.
What's not normal is that the quality doesn't return to its
previous level once the call has ended.

To explain :

Bluetooth has a limited capacity for moving data between your
computer and your headphones/headset. To best use that bandwidth,
the transmissions are compressed.

Once a call comes in, the driver needs to reserve bandwidth for the
audio coming from the microphone, which means that the audio to the
headphones has less bandwidth available and needs to be more
heavily compressed, resulting in lower audio quality.

What you can do :

- You should check that you have installed the
  latest driver for your Airpods.
- Check if that driver has an settings page where some such setting
  is available.
- Disconnect and reconnect the Airpods (turn them off and on)
- Contact the Support team of the manufacturer for advice.